# Workflow Completed Event for correct workflow

Tags: workflow, visual-studio

Im writing an workflow event receiver that fires on workflowcompleted for a list. If I have two workflows on that list, how can I restrict the completed event to check its happening for the correct workflow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [SPWorkflowEventProperties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.workflow.spworkfloweventproperties_members%28v=office.14%29.aspx) you should be able to get the name of the workflow association from which the workflow instance was created.

```
public override void WorkflowCompleted(SPWorkflowEventProperties properties)
{
    SPWorkflowActivationProperties activationProperties = properties.ActivationProperties;
    string worflowAssociationName = activationProperties.TemplateName;

    //compare is it for the workflow you want to work with here

}
```

**EDIT**

It turns out that ActivationProperties is null in WorkflowCompleted event.

A workaround is to use SPWorkflowEventProperties.InstanceId to get the related task and then from the task item get other details, like the related item, the workflow, etc.

```
private const string WfInstanceQuery = @"<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='WorkflowInstanceID'/><Value Type='GUID'>{0}</Value></Eq></Where>"; 

SPList wfTaskList = web.Lists["TasksListName"]; 
var items = wfTaskList.GetItems(new SPQuery() 
{ 
    Query = string.Format(WfInstanceQuery, properties.InstanceId.ToString()) 
}); 

if (items.Count > 0) 
{ 
    Guid listId = new Guid(items[0]["WorkflowListId"].ToString()); 
    int itemId = (int)items[0]["WorkflowItemId"]; 
    //Get the List item on which the workflow run 
    SPListItem item = web.Lists[listId].GetItemById(itemId); 
    SPWorkflow workflow = item.Workflows[new Guid(properties.InstanceId.ToString())];
    //check the workflow here
}
```

[Source](http://blog.symprogress.com/2011/09/sp-2010-get-workflow-status-workflowcompleted-event/)

Comment: ActivationProperties is null in WorkflowCompleted

Comment: Hmm, try with InstanceId which shouldn't be null. Check [this](http://blog.symprogress.com/2011/09/sp-2010-get-workflow-status-workflowcompleted-event/) post to get the workflow name through the task item. It may work for your case too.

Comment: Good. I edited the answer with the reference.